# LinkButton as Default Button

Tags: asp.net

```
HtmlForm fMp = Master.FindControl("fMp") as HtmlForm;
            if (fMp != null)
            {
                fMp.DefaultButton = btnLogin.UniqueID;
            }
```

but when i press enter nothing happens. Any idea why?

if i use:

```
fMp.DefaultButton = "btnLogin";
```

then i get:

> The DefaultButton of 'fMp' must be the
>   ID of a control of type
>   IButtonControl.

isn't LinkedButton part of IButtonControl. I google but no solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only **Button and ImageButton** controls are supported as DefaultButton.Check this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton(VS.85).aspx) article if you need to confirm.